# How to install more then one SSL on Windows 2008/IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

We searched about this topic here and found lot of posts that cover different parts from this topic but we didn't find and answer for our solution.

Problem:

- We have Windows 2008 Server with IIS7
  and we would like to install more
  then one SSL on this server.
- We have one IP address for this
  server but maybe we could get more of
  them, and we found that we can have only one SSL on one IP address

Questions:

- If we are not wrong, we can have only
  one SSL on Windows 2008 / IIS7 if we
  have only one IP?
- We found SSL certificates for
  multiple domains but this is not
  suitable for us because in green box
  in Address bar will be visible only
  one company (this is suitable for one
  company that has multiple websites). So the only option is to buy different SSL for each different company and what is the best way to set IIS7 to support this?
- Can we host different websites (each
  with its own SSL) on same IIS7
  webserver? What are our options?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately it is not currently possible to have multiple SSL certificates issued to multiple domains on a single IP address.  There has to be a one to one relationship between SSL certificate, domain and IP.  So you only option is to get additional IP address for the server.

You can use Host Headers to partially solve the problem, but inferring from your question I assume you have already encountered this and disregarding it as a viable option.  Just incase anybody is googling and finds this question:

Host Headers allows you to bind a single certificate (multidomain or wildcard) to multiple domains on a single IP address, for example:

```
              sub1.mydomain.com
192.168.0.1 > sub2.mydomain.com > SSL: *.mydomain.com
              sub3.mydomain.com
```

More info on how to configure this can be found here:

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html

Comment: Have we given up on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)? Does this look like a programming question?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using different port than 443 with same ip.

Plus; have a look: [Using Host Headers and SSL in IIS 7 (without the ugliness of appcmd)](http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=80)

Comment: Thank you! Almost missed this guys, big tip!

Answer (score 0):

If you need each website to show a different company in the certificate, the only option available currently is getting additional IP addresses. You will simply create additional IIS websites and bind them to the new IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a Microsoft rule, Windows Server 2008 R2 can't be upgraded to IIS 8, the maximum IIS version is 7.x; however I found a way to have more than one SSL sites using the same default HTTPS port (443) by the Host Headers mechanism.  It is mentioned [here](http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=80) and if you need clarifications about the Host Headers mechanism you can take a look [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9843/69/using-host-headers-on-iis-675/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer that came a little bit late (about 11 years after), but who use Windows Server 2008 in 2022? Using SNI this is easy solvable now...